# How to play two sounds at the same time?

Tags: android, audio, dart, flutter

I've been trying a few things with sounds in flutter lately . Using audioPlayer plugin.

But I'm facing a wall. I have both a background music, and small sounds effects. 
The problem is that I can't play both at once. If I play the background music, then the sound effect won't play. And the opposite works too.

Any idea about how to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with the [audioplayer](https://github.com/rxlabz/audioplayer) plugin and there's an [issue](https://github.com/rxlabz/audioplayer/issues/4) open for it already. The author has indicated that he's open to pull requests if you'd like to take a crack at implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use media players. Use this code to set up the background music:

```
MediaPlayer backgroundMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(PATH_TO_BACKGROUND_MUSIC));
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Then replace PATH_TO_BACKGROUND_MUSIC with the background music path.

Then when you want your sound effect to happen, use this code:

```
MediaPlayer soundEffectMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(PATH_TO_SOUND_EFFECT));
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Then replace PATH_TO_SOUND_EFFECT with the background music path.

You can learn for about media players [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this won't work. It isn't a native android app. But an app done using Flutter's framework, in dartlang.

Comment: This gives a `MediaPlayer finalized without being released` error.