# is there any way to play 2 sound files by just a click?

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to play 2 different sound files at the same time, but the problem is that it plays only one
any advice would be appreciated

```
 //onClicks
    ni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ham.isChecked() && sem.isChecked()) {
                if (!niMP.isPlaying() && !niMPs.isPlaying()) {
                    niMP.setLooping(true);
                    niMP.start();
                    niMPs.setLooping(true);
                    niMPs.start();
                } else
                    niMP.pause();
                    niMP.seekTo(0);
                    niMPs.pause();
                    niMPs.seekTo(0);
```

Comment: thanks for responding! but it didn't work!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945790/how-to-play-two-sounds-at-the-same-time) might help you.

Comment: Please share more relevant code, like- object creation of `niMP` and `niMPs`, if possible share the full activity

Comment: thanks guys, i've solved it by mixing the two files with an audio editor app. all what i needed was just to think out of the box! thanks again